# CentOs 7 : ssl_stapling_init_cert

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, centos7, ispconfig

I have setup my web server with CentOs 7 (I use the tutorial HowToForge), when i try to access to ISPConfig (**.**.**.**:8080), the page display the presentation page of Apache HTTP Server, but not the panel of ISPConfig.

Error file :

> [ssl:error] [pid 1096] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate!
>
> [ssl:error] [pid 1096] AH02235: Unable to configure server certificate for stapling

This is the report of ISPConfig :

```html
##### SERVER ##### 
IP-address (as per hostname): ***.***.***.*** 
[WARN] could not determine server's ip address by ifconfig 
[INFO] ISPConfig is installed. 

##### ISPCONFIG ##### 
ISPConfig version is 3.1.7 


##### VERSION CHECK ##### 

[INFO] php (cli) version is 5.6.31 

##### PORT CHECK ##### 

[WARN] Port 465 (SMTP server SSL) seems NOT to be listening 
[WARN] Port 22 (SSH server) seems NOT to be listening 

##### MAIL SERVER CHECK ##### 

[WARN] I found no "submission" entry in your postfix master.cf 
[INFO] this is not critical, but if you want to offer port 587 for smtp connections you have to enable th 
is. 
[WARN] I found no "smtps" entry in your postfix master.cf 
[INFO] this is not critical, but if you want to offer SSL for smtp (not TLS) connections you have to enab 
le this. 

##### RUNNING SERVER PROCESSES ##### 

[INFO] I found the following web server(s): 
Unknown process (httpd) (PID 28680) 
[INFO] I found the following mail server(s): 
Postfix (PID 31745) 
[INFO] I found the following pop3 server(s): 
Dovecot (PID 31794) 
[INFO] I found the following imap server(s): 
Dovecot (PID 31794) 
[INFO] I found the following ftp server(s): 
PureFTP (PID 30339) 

##### LISTENING PORTS ##### 
(seulement () 
Adresse (distante) 
[localhost]:10027 (31745/master) 
[anywhere]:110 (31794/dovecot) 
[anywhere]:143 (31794/dovecot) 
[anywhere]:111 (1/systemd) 
[anywhere]:21 (30339/pure-ftpd) 
***.***.***.***:53 (31854/named) 
[localhost]:53 (31854/named) 
[localhost]:953 (31854/named) 
[anywhere]:25 (31745/master) 
[anywhere]:993 (31794/dovecot) 
[anywhere]:995 (31794/dovecot) 
[localhost]:10024 (31771/amavisd) 
[localhost]:10025 (31745/master) 
[localhost]:10026 (31771/amavisd) 
[anywhere]:3306 (31615/mysqld) 
[localhost]10 (31794/dovecot) 
[localhost]43 (31794/dovecot) 
[localhost]11 (1/systemd) 
*:*:*:*::*:8080 (28680/httpd) 
*:*:*:*::*:80 (28680/httpd) 
*:*:*:*::*:8081 (28680/httpd) 
*:*:*:*::*:21 (30339/pure-ftpd) 
*:*:*:*::*:53 (31854/named) 
*:*:*:*::*:953 (31854/named) 
*:*:*:*::*:25 (31745/master) 
*:*:*:*::*:443 (28680/httpd) 
*:*:*:*::*:993 (31794/dovecot) 
*:*:*:*::*:995 (31794/dovecot) 
*:*:*:*::*:10024 (31771/amavisd) 
*:*:*:*::*:10026 (31771/amavisd) 




##### IPTABLES ##### 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target prot opt source destination 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) 
target prot opt source destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target prot opt source destination
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Are you accessing ISPConfig by IP address or by hostname? Does the hostname have the proper DNS entries?

Comment: I tried with both. I'm on a local network, I just modified the "hosts" file.

Comment: If when configured ISPConfig, the hostname you have chosen for your server is not a real hostname (like subdomain.domain.tld), then this might be your issue. You can try to use it without SSL, just to test if it works or not

Comment: Ok but normally, localhost:8080 or ip:8080 should work no ?

Comment: ip:8080 should work. localhost:8080 won't work unless you have an X server installed on the ISPConfig server and you run a browser and try to access it locally. Over the network, localhost will point to your actual computer and not to your ispconfig server

Comment: And if I disabled SSL, my PHPMyAdmin could not work

Comment: What has to do PhpMyAdmin with SSL? phpmyadmin works on both http:// and https:// connections...

Comment: Ok, I have already the same problem.

Comment: You're not quite providing answers to my questions so it's pretty hard to debug and help you... Sorry

Comment: On my server machine, I "just" set the ip address and install different plugins (see tuto centos7 on HowToForge). It was at the time I wanted to set up the site via ISPConfig that I detected the SSL errors. I try to follow your instructions (deactivated SSL or try to connect with the ip address of the machine to ISPConfig but it does not work).